# how to know the index of item of datalist when button clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i have a image in the datalist

```
        <asp:DataList ID="dlHotels" runat="server" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
        <img id="opener" class="btn12" alt="" src="images/view.jpg" />
       </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
```

when i click the image jquery is called

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
        $("#opener").click(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
 });
```

now in this jquery a popup appear which is div
and outside of the datalist

```
<div id="dialog" title="Choose Your Dates">
</div>
```

now what i want when div appear it should know through which image it is called.

Comment: I'm not surprised that nothing appear. Where is dialog and opener id declaration ?

Comment: no that is not my problem div is appearing but i want to know index of datalist

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can't use the generic id opener, because when the backend render the html code the id name is compute with an indexer, for not have the same ID identifier multiple times.

For this use case you can try this :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlHotels" runat="server" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <img id="opener" class="btn12" alt="" src="images/view.jpg" onclick="openMe(this)" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Now modify your javascript code with this :

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
//        $("#opener").click(function () {
//
//            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
//        });
 });

function openMe (p_whoIs)
{
   //for debug use, comment the next line in procduction environment
   alert("You call me with : " + p_whoIs);

 var $img = $(p_whoIs).clone();
 $("#dialog").append($img);

   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog(p_whoIs.id); not working its only work when dialog("open").